# MySQL CAST loses decimal digits when source is result from a regexp, but works fine on the same string when its hardcoded

Tags: mysql, casting

I'm getting completely perplexing results here... I boiled it down to this:

```
select
    regexp_substr('56.948959;24.121503|56.950469;24.119765', '^[0-9\.]+') raw_txt,
    cast('56.948959' as decimal(10,8)) just_cast,
    case when regexp_substr('56.948959;24.121503|56.950469;24.119765', '^[0-9\.]+') = '56.948959' then 'yisss' else 'nope' end text_comparison,
    cast(regexp_substr('56.948959;24.121503|56.950469;24.119765', '^[0-9\.]+') as decimal(10,8)) full_decimal,
    cast(regexp_substr('56.948959;24.121503|56.950469;24.119765', '^[0-9\.]+') as double) full_double
```

And the results that I get are:

```
raw_txt: 56.948959
just_cast: 56.94895900
text_comparison: yisss
full_decimal: 56.00000000
full_double: 56.948959
```

Where are the decimal digits in the `full_decimal` case? Why does the cast work fine when run on a simple string (`just_cast`), but not when **the exact same string** (see `text_comparison`) comes from a regexp match? And yet it works if we cast to a `double` instead? What is going on here?

MySQL version: 8.0.21

Comment: Works fine in mariadb too so perhaps a bug in mysql.

Comment: You may use not REGEXP_SUBSTR() but SUBSTRING_INDEX().

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291836/why-does-casting-this-string-as-a-decimal-fail

Comment: @ErgestBasha - Wonderful, thank you! :) If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Vilx- added only if the original answer will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reported as a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61691).

If you cast first to char and then re-cast to decimal the cast works.

For example:

```
select cast(cast(regexp_substr('56.948959;24.121503|56.950469;24.119765', '^[0-9\.]+') as char(100)) as decimal(10,8)) full_decimal
```

[Full answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291836/why-does-casting-this-string-as-a-decimal-fail)